# proc_open in php

Tags: php, proc-open

I am using `proc_ope`n in PHP to open a Application such as **tclsh.exe**. 
This returns a resource number .

Now my question is how do i know if the *tclsh* process is killed in the script ?

Regards
Mithun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[proc_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php)